# How can I normalise MySQL tables with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables fruits and colors.

In the fruits table, the `cid` column references the `c_id` from the color table, but the problem is that the colors table, has duplicate color names:

[image]

Is there an effective way in MySQL to remove the duplicate color rows and update the `cid` in the foods table accordingly so the result will be something like this?

[image]

Comment: You could just run a query for every color you remove. `UPDATE fruits SET cid='1' WHERE cid='7'`, then remove the `c_id` `7` from the table. Repeat for each color until there are no duplicates, then don't let there be duplicates again (make `c_name` unique). If it were me, I would automate this using PHP (my experience) or some other language, would be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is a foreign key constraint between the tables, you first need to `update` table `fruit`. For this, you can `join` the tables to get the color name, and then retrieve the minimum `c_id` of that color using a correlated subquery:

```
update fruit f
inner join color c on f.cid = c.c_id
set f.cid = (select min(c_id) from color c1 where c1.name = c.c_name)
```

Then you can safely delete the duplicate `color`s while keeping the one with the lowest `c_id`:

```
delete c
from color c
inner join color c1 on c1.c_name = c.c_name and c1.c_id < c.c_id
```

Comment: Thank you! The Update query worked just fine, but the delete query throws an error: "c" is not valid at this position, expecting : EOF, ':'

Comment: @Csaba: I updated the delete query, please let me know if it works better now.

Comment: Now the code looks valid, but when I execute the code I get: "Table 'c' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and a separate source for data"

Comment: @Csaba: ok, I changed it to a `JOIN`ed query. I tested it and this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could get yourself a result set that has the minimum `cid` of matching colors for each `f_id`

```
SELECT fruit.f_id, fruit.f_name, min(c2.c_id) as c_id
FROM
    fruit
    INNER JOIN color c1 ON fruit.cid = c1.c_id
    INNER JOIN color c2 ON cl.c_name = c2.c_name
GROUP BY fruit.f_id, fruit.f_name
```

That's not the most efficient query, but it will work. You can use this to set your `fruit` table correct to only reference a single `color` when there are duplicates.

After fixing your `fruit` table you can then run a query to see which colors are unused so you know what to delete:

```
SELECT color.*
FROM color
  LEFT OUTER JOIN fruit on color.c_id = fruit.cid
WHERE fruit.f_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I think you meant to join c1 and c2 on c_name

Comment: @Uueerdo Sure did. Fixed. Yikes.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to update fruit to only reference one of each color name:

```
UPDATE fruit AS f 
INNER JOIN color As c ON f.cid = c.c_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT c_name, MIN(c_id) AS firstCid FROM color GROUP BY c_name) AS firsts
ON c.c_name = firsts.c_name
SET f.c_id = firsts.firstCid
;
```

*Note: this is similar to GMB's answer, but does not use a correlated subquery.*

Then, the duplicates can be cleaned up with something like this ...

```
DELETE 
FROM colors 
WHERE c_id NOT IN (
     SELECT MIN(c_id) 
     FROM colors 
     GROUP BY c_name
   )
```

this will preserve unused colors as well, however....

MySQL does not usually like queries that select and delete from the same table simultaneously, so it might have to be expressed like so to "trick" MySQL:

```
DELETE 
FROM colors 
WHERE c_id NOT IN (
     SELECT * 
     FROM (
         SELECT MIN(c_id) 
         FROM colors 
         GROUP BY c_name
     ) AS firstIds
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in steps -

**1. Delete the duplicates-**

```
DELETE FROM colors C1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM colors C2
              WHERE C2.c_name = C1.c_name
              AND C2.c_id > C1.c_id);
```

**2. Reset the c_id-**

```
UPDATE colors C1
JOIN
(
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, c_id, c_name
    FROM colors
    CROSS JOIN (select @rownum := 0) rn
) AS C2 ON C1.c_name = C2.c_name
SET C1.c_id = C2.rownum
```

Comment: If `fruit.cid` has a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade, that will end up wiping a lot of fruit data; if it has no constraint at all, information like a banana being yellow will need manually reproduced.